# Edit feature on Opengeo Layer

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite

My requirement is to add,edit and delete feature(Polygon, Line etc..) on opengeo layer and save the changes to oracle spatial database.

Opengeo version is and following the below url for the same
http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html

Issue is, the request is not going to the geoserver. I have noticed this in browser's netowk tab.

```
var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();

                  layer2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(requestedLayer, {
                        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
                        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection(epsgvalue),
                        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                            version: "1.1.0",
                            srsName: epsgvalue,
                            vendorParams: {'viewparams':viewParams},

                            url: "http://x.x.x.x/geoserver/wfs",
                            featureNS :  "http://x.x.x.x/geoserver/capacity/org",
                            featureType: requestedLayer,
                            geometryName: "the_geom"
                           // schema: "http://x.x.x.x/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=requestedLayer"
                        })
                    }); 


                  alert(layer2);

             map.addLayer(layer2);
```

Regards,
Srikanth

Comment: Try to give more info, are you using OpenLayers.ProxyHost or not? Otherwise you might run into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: are you using a proxy? what do you see in your browser's developer tools? Where are you running the code from? from a web server or form your file system?

Comment: Yes. Iam using proxy..

Comment: Yes. Iam using proxy.. Idon't think it's a proxy issue. The below WFS url is working from my application
http://x.x.x.x/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&outputFormat=JSON&request=GetFeature&typename=capacity:BOUNDS_LAYER&maxfeatures=1&viewparams=spatial_table:TABLE_NAME